# Pathfinding function crashes Unity?

Tags: unity, path-finding, recursion

I've been trying to add this pathfinding function to my program, but when I run it, it just crashes. I've read other threads and this might be an infinite loop, but I don't see where it would be other than the recursion area (and it shouldn't break there because of the if-statement checking if it's out of bounds).

```
public void SetPath(Vector3 pos, Vector3 goal, Queue<Vector3> p, List<Vector3> visited, int cost) {

     Debug.Log("checking " + pos);

     //method which checks if the target tile is outside of the map
     if (core.OutOfBounds((int)goal.x, (int)goal.z))
         Debug.LogError("target tile " + goal + " is out of bounds!");

     //if the current position isn't out of bounds and hasn't been visited
     else if (!core.OutOfBounds((int)pos.x, (int)pos.z) && !visited.Contains(pos)) {

         Debug.Log("pos is within the limits of the map");

         //add tile to the visited list and path queue
         visited.Add(pos);
         p.Enqueue(pos);

         //add tile movement cost to total path cost
         cost += core.TileCost((int)pos.x, (int)pos.z);

         //if the current position is the target tile and the path is shorter than the current one
         if (pos == goal && cost < shortestPath) {
             Debug.Log("pos is the target tile");
             shortestPath = cost;
             path = p;
         }

         //else, check tiles around
         else {

             SetPath(new Vector3(pos.x + 1, 0, pos.z), goal, p, visited, cost);

             SetPath(new Vector3(pos.x, 0, pos.z + 1), goal, p, visited, cost);

             SetPath(new Vector3(pos.x - 1, 0, pos.z), goal, p, visited, cost);

             SetPath(new Vector3(pos.x, 0, pos.z - 1), goal, p, visited, cost);

         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function will recurse over the entire grid doing so very inefficiently.

If you have a 500 x 500 grid that will cause a (nearly) 250,000 deep call stack.

The solution: Use a `Queue<Vector3>` of **positions to visit** and a while-loop that consumes the queue rather than a recursive call. Also to speed up the visited check use a 2D array of visited `bool` rather than a linear `List<Vector3>` search.

---

But to explain what's happening right now, for example if you start at (0, 0, 0) and the exit is at (1, 0, 1) this is what it will do (I've shorten it from step 17 onward)

*For brievity I call (Z+1) down, (Z-1) up, (X+1) right, and (X-1) left in the explanation as if it was a 2D map in classic 2D orientation replacing Y with Z*

1. it will first recurse over `SetPath(new Vector3(pos.x + 1, 0, pos.z), ...)` until it hits the right-side boundary,
2. then return once,
3. then recurse once over `SetPath(new Vector3(pos.x, 0, pos.z + 1), ...)`
4. then `SetPath(new Vector3(pos.x + 1, 0, pos.z), ...)` hit the right side boundary
5. then return once,
6. REPEAT FROM 3 and recurse until it hits the bottom boundary
7. then return once,
8. then recurse once over `SetPath(new Vector3(pos.x - 1, 0, pos.z), ...)`
9. then recurse once over `SetPath(new Vector3(pos.x + 1, 0, pos.z), ...)` hit visited
10. then return once
11. then recurse once over `SetPath(new Vector3(pos.x, 0, pos.z + 1), ...)`, hit boundary
12. then return once
13. then recurse once over `SetPath(new Vector3(pos.x - 1, 0, pos.z), ...)`
14. REPEAT FROM 9 and recurse until it hit left boundary
15. then recurse once over `SetPath(new Vector3(pos.x, 0, pos.z - 1), ...)`, (going up)
16. then recurse over `SetPath(new Vector3(pos.x + 1, 0, pos.z), ...)` all the way to the rightmost column that got visited.
17. Try down: visited, return
18. Try left: visited, return
19. Recurse up,
20. Try right: visited, return
21. Try down: visited, return
22. Recurse left,
23. REPEAT FROM 20, until left boundary is reached
24. REPEAT FROM 15, **snaking its way back up very slowly eating up at the stack recursing on every cell until it crawls back up to (1, 0, 1)** or the stack overflows.

[image]

Every visited cell is 1 recursion on the stack until the end is reached, then returns until it finds an unvisited cell, then recurse again until they're all visited.

Comment: Also if you do around 500 Debug.Log or Debug.LogError at once (more or less depending on your computer's power) the Unity editor takes an eternity to process and print them in the editor UI making it look like Unity froze.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! :) I've just put in the 2D bool array, but can you explain how to implement the queue of positions to visit?

Comment: The URL gets cut off by the SE comment system, had to quote it  `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm`